# Read from a file and store it in classes(objects?) visual basic

Tags: vb.net

I am new to Visual Basic.

I tried to build a Student mark sheet, so I wanted to read from a text file that includes student name, student ID and their marks. I know how to read the whole text from text fine, But I need to store each part to the Classes of students

For example, The text file has

1 Tom 90

2 Jay 95

3 Ben 78

How could I read the first line, store 1 into one variable, Tom into another etc and then read the second line again, and so on?

Here is the code read from the text file I found on the internet.

```
 Dim fileReader As System.IO.StreamReader
fileReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader("C:\\testfile.txt")
Dim stringReader As String
stringReader = fileReader.ReadLine()
MsgBox("The first line of the file is " & stringReader)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This site isn't a code writing service. Please take a moment to re-read the guidelines for asking questions here in the [Help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help). But sometimes ...

Comment: I'd recommend searching StackOverflow, Google or dotnetperls.com before asking here.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you need a delimiter such as a comma. You can also serialize the data into a XML file. The best you can do right now is to use a space as the delimiter but that is rigid solution because that means you cannot use spaces in your data. The best solution is to store the information into a database.

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned by *@Teach Me How To Sell* your data lines are not well formed. Using following code snippet is only for single words to use well. Try to insert another delimiter.

Take each `part` of a line and store to a variable for your needs.

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
  Private Sub btnReadTextFile_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnReadTextFile.Click
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    ' Loop over lines in file.
    For Each line As String In File.ReadLines("D:\_working\foobar-students.txt")
      ' Display the line.
      MessageBox.Show(line)
      ' Split the line by delimiter
      Dim parts As String() = line.Split(" ")
      ' Loop over each string received.
      Dim part As String
      For Each part In parts
        ' Display to console.
        Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}", i, part)
        ' Add code to store each part for your needs
        ' ...
      Next
      i += 1
    Next
  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Upvote and check as answer would be great if the answer was useful for your needs.